# Cassandra 0.7.10 - Can't create column family with key_validation_class using cassandra cli

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-0.7

I've been using cassandra-cli and have been trying to create a column family with the key as type TimeUUIDType.

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY users WITH COMPARATOR = UTF8Type AND key_validation_class = TimeUUIDType;
```

Whenever I use this command I get the following error...

```
No enum constant org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliUserHelp.ColumnFamilyArguement.KEY_VALIDATION_CLASS
```

How do I ever set the key validation class when creating a column family using cassandra cli?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Key validation wasn't added to Cassandra until 0.8.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2311